# Why are moderator election months are not the same?

Tags: discussion, moderator-election

I wonder why elections take place on a different month each year.

Shouldn't they be held on a certain month of the year? So if I want to cast a vote next year I would be expecting it to be in that certain month.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question because of the down votes? Please explain so I would know what not to.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Moderator elections are not scheduled events; they are called when there is a need for new moderators.

As such, the fact that the last 3 elections have been roughly a year apart each time has been a coincidence.

Comment: That's a helluva coincidence, though.

Comment: @Makoto: I guess that moderators are humans too and push for anniversaries before resigning. *I'm sure I can make it to another whole year!*

Comment: Its a great responsibility though but also human feel good that "I am the admin of "SO"".

Comment: The real truth is that @Martijn informed someone at SO that he was ready to officially be a mod, so they started an election. :P